# Meteor Lepozepo cloudinary $ is not defined

Tags: javascript, meteor, cloudinary

I am trying to use the lepozepo:cloudinary package, but I receive an error regarding this code.

```
$.cloudinary.config({
  cloud_name: "dx8pjibvk"
});
```

The error states:  `ReferenceError: $ is not defined`

Jquery is installed. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Where exactly do you write that code? If it's in a `lib` folder it might be executed too early. Try this:

```
Meteor.startup(function(){
  if(Meteor.isClient){
    $.cloudinary.config({
      cloud_name: "dx8pjibvk"
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: As I am new to meteor, it is not in any folder within the project directory. Should I place the file in a certain folder?

Comment: That's why. You should separate client code from server code using sub-folders. Checkout [http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/structuringyourapp) to find out more. But nobody forces you to do that, my code should work if you leave it at the root of your project because I've added `Meteor.isClient`. Have fun with Meteor.